# Filtering Django model to get the last index

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Is it possible to filter Django model to get the last index.

Here is my view

```
order = Order.objects.reverse("order_number")[-1]
```

But it gets the first index.

Answer (score 4):

The subscript `[-1]` selects the *last* item in a list or tuple and, given that the query set was reversed, this would be the *first* item, not the last. You could try:

```
order = Order.objects.reverse("order_number")[0]
```

but you can't pass a sort key to `reverse()` so this code would fail. If you have a default sorting order set up for the table you can just do this:

```
order = Order.objects.last()
```

It might be better to use an explicit `order_by()`:

```
order = Order.objects.order_by("order_number").last()
```

Comment: I would put in bold: *those will work only when you sort queryset by pk* :)
otherwise Max('pk') should be used

Comment: @Jerzyk: If the query set has no defined ordering, `last()` will automatically sort it by the primary key. This would be the same as `Max('pk')`. But in Django `order_number` is very like _not_ the primary key, hence an explicit sort on the `order_number` field should be done (unless one is certain that the ordering is defined in the model).

Comment: this is what I meant, and I asked to add it to main body of the answer (especially this Max() part) - to have complete answer (sorry for mistake z 'pk' instaead 'order_numner')

Answer (score 3):

Try [lastest(field_name=None)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

`Entry.objects.latest('id')`